# Load ReactJS as a CDN and render simple hello

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello!</h1>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to basically print **Hello!**  in React. I imported ReactJS and ReactDOM as CDNs. Seems this is not working. I think browser doesn't understand JSX? How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Enable babel (Use BabelJS checkmark) within snippet to read JSX

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov How do I do that?

Comment: @PathumKalhan Please go through https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support

Comment: Updated your code. Just need to select `Use BabelJS / ES2015` checkbox on left side bottom.

Comment: Edit your snippet, and click 'Use BabelJS / ES2015' checkmark in the bottom of left pane

Comment: Assuming you want to run this outside of stack-snippets, you can use babel-standalone like so: https://jsfiddle.net/afjnm9ux/

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [JSX syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) which browsers are not supporting. You could use `React.createElement` or a transpiler (like babel) to convert JSX to `React.createElement`

Here is a cdn for it

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

You can read in details about how to use and implement a JSX transpiler in your repo [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#optional-try-react-with-jsx)